# Correlation between two linear sums of several products of random variables

Tags: correlation, variance, random-variable, independence

I would like to understand the correlation between two linear sums of several products of random variables. Well, it is quite difficult to describe the exact question I have. Basically I want to understand if there are any properties of the correlation between the two variables $U$ and $V$.

$\text{U}_i = \text{X}_i\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{ik}b_{ik}$

$\text{V}_i = \text{X}_i\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{ik}c_{ik}$

or given as vectors

$ \text{U}=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 \text{X}_1 a_{11}b_{11}+\text{X}_1 a_{12}b_{12}+...+\text{X}_1 a_{1m} b_{1m}\\
 \text{X}_2 a_{21} b_{21}+ \text{X}_2 a_{22} b_{22}+...+  \text{X}_2 a_{2m} b_{2m}\\
 \vdots\\
 \text{X}_n a_{n1} b_{n1}+ \text{X}_n a_{n2} b_{n2}+...+ \text{X}_n a_{nm} b_{nm}\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

$ \text{V}=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 \text{X}_1 a_{11}c_{11}+\text{X}_1 a_{12}c_{12}+...+\text{X}_1 a_{1m} c_{1m}\\
 \text{X}_2 a_{21} c_{21}+ \text{X}_2 a_{22} c_{22}+...+  \text{X}_2 a_{2m} c_{2m}\\
 \vdots\\
 \text{X}_n a_{n1} c_{n1}+ \text{X}_n a_{n2} c_{n2}+...+ \text{X}_n a_{nm} c_{nm}\\
 \end{bmatrix}$

I have tried using programming with random data and found, indeed, the two vectors have a strong correlation ($\rho$>0.5). Additionally, the larger $m$ is, the larger $\rho$ is. Does anyone have a mathematic explanation for that?

Any related references are appreciated.

## Edits

Note that $X$, $a$, $b$, $c$ are random variables.

Comment: This is a  strange question, because (assuming the small latin letters are all constants) $U$ and $V$ can much more simply be written $U_i = \lambda_i X_i$ and $V_i=\mu_i X_i$ for constants $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i,$ and in this form it is straightforward to express the covariances between the $U_i$ and $V_j$ in terms of those of the $X_i$ and $X_j.$  Are you sure you have accurately expressed your question?

Comment: It is not entirely true because a common term $a_{ik}$ is in both $\lambda_i$ and $u_i$ in your notation. All $X$, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are random variables.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to express the question in plain language, but I can share a piece of pseudo-code to illustrate it (hope it is allowed).

n   =   100;  

m   =   100;

X   =   rand(n,1);     

a   =   rand(n,m);

b   =   rand(n,m);

c   =   rand(n,m);

for i = 1: n 

    U(i) = sum(X(i)*a(i,:).*b(i,:));

    V(i) = sum(X(i)*a(i,:).*c(i,:));

end 


In this case, the correlation coefficient between $U$ and $V$ is 0.9785.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify which symbols refer to random variables and which ones to numbers.

Comment: @whuber Sorry for not being clear, all the symbols refer to random variables.